# CrudRepository findById dont return java.util. Optional

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

public interface LmsRepository extends CrudRepository
I have no findOne method for getting single count so when i using findById I got this exception."Property [id] not found on type [java.util.Optional]" How can i solve this trouble ?

This is my CrudRepo

```
@Repository
public interface LmsRepository extends CrudRepository<Book, Long> {


}
```

Entity File

```
@Entity(name="lms_tbl")
public class Book {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;

@Column(name="book_name")
private String bookName;

private String author;

@Column(name="purchase_date")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date purchaseDate;

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

and other....
```

Service File

```
@Service
public class LmsService {

@Autowired
private LmsRepository lmsRepository;

public Collection<Book> findAllBooks(){
    ArrayList<Book> books = new ArrayList<Book>();
    for (Book book : lmsRepository.findAll()) {
        books.add(book);
    }

    return books;
}

public void deleteBook(long id) {

    lmsRepository.deleteById(id);
}

public Optional<Book> findById(Long id) {

    return lmsRepository.findById(id);
}
```

}

Controller File

```
@Controller
public class MainController {

@Autowired
private LmsService lmsService;


@GetMapping("/")
public String index(HttpServletRequest req) {
    req.setAttribute("books", lmsService.findAllBooks());
    req.setAttribute("mode","BOOK_VIEW");
    return "index";
}

@GetMapping("/updateBook")
public String index(@RequestParam Long id,HttpServletRequest req) {
    req.setAttribute("book", lmsService.findById(id));
    req.setAttribute("mode","BOOK_EDIT");
    return "index";
}
```

}

I tried add new method in CrudRepo but it doesnt work.

Comment: Kindly post some code!

Comment: Spring Data JPA supports Optional, so when done correctly, it should work (like here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/jpa/java8). @Zülküf could you please post the whole interface definition of LmsRepository?

Comment: @dunni  Thanks for your helping.

Answer (score 9):

In your service class change this

```
public Optional<Book> findById(Long id) {
    return lmsRepository.findById(id);
}
```

to this

```
public Book findById(Long id) {
    return lmsRepository.findById(id).get();
}
```

Explanation: `Optional` is a wrapper class  which may or may not contain a non-null value. You get that error because you are trying to insert `Optional` in the model, not `Book`. As `Optional` does not contain any `id` field, you get the error. `Optional` is used for having defalut values of throwing exception when you have a null object where you do not expect it to be null. You can create for example an automatic exception throwing in case of null optional. For example, you can upgrade your service in this way:

```
public Book findById(Long id) {
    return lmsRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(RuntimeException::new);
}
```

This will throw a `RuntimeException` any time `Book` is null inside the `Optional`, or will give you back the value of the `Book` class.

A more elegant solution is the following:

```
public Book findById(Long id) {
    return lmsRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(NotFoundException::new);
}
```

having:

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
public class NotFoundException extends RuntimeException{
}
```

In this way when the optional contains a `Book`, that is returned back to the controller and inserted in model. If the `Optional` contains a null value then `NotFoundException` will be thrown, it does not need to be catched, and will be mappet to 404 HTTP error.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a method in your interface

```
@Repository
public interface LmsRepository extends CrudRepository<Book, Long> {
Optional<Book> findById(Long id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create own methods in the repository.

```
LmsRepository<CustomClass> extends CrudRepository<CustomClass> {
  Optional<CustomClass> findById(int id);
}
```

Comment: Actually trouble what I can't show "optional<Book>"  result in jsp . I am sending variable to jsp with HttpServletRequest setAttribute

Comment: @ZülküfADSIZ you have to use `.get()` or `.else` to extract the book entity and then set the attribute with the extracted book.

Answer (score 0):

in your entity you declare @Id on id, so findById follow on this (primary key) datatype, id of the entity the repository manages.

Comment: for deep info read this:
https://www.petrikainulainen.net/spring-data-jpa-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

Simply put `.get()` after `lmsRepository.findById(id).get()`;

`.get()` parses and will return the [object of lms] caught from the database

No need to override, implement and et cetera.